# Does display - swap rescues website loading times?

Tags: fonts, frontend

I want to load 3 different fonts from Google (I know this is not ideal) and Google fonts specifically tell me that load times will me Moderate!

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:700|Oswald|Roboto:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

But with the display=swap, in theory, it shouldn't impact any loading time since it will load some default fonts until it is ready to fetch them.

My question is if this at the end of the day does not impact page speed load but only costs more bandwidth to the user and slower loading fonts (since it's 1 too many).

Answer (score 0):

The `display` in those Google Fonts URLs refers to the `font-display` property that defines how the browser will handle things until your font is downloaded. It doesn't have any impact (per spec, at least) on when the browser decides to load the font.  It just describes how things will look until the font is downloaded.  In other words, this property is about how your page looks while it's loading, not about optimization per se.